# Is it possible to create a custom transition in winrt? (like ContentThemeTransition)

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a custom transition instead of using the the standard set of transitions.

Especially I'd like to have a customized AddDeleteTransition when replacing a ListViewItem.

I think I have to inherit from the Transition class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.transition.ASPx) but I have no clue what to to in this class, as I can't find any samples. (I know how to create and use Storyboards and Animations)

In the end, I want to to something like this in xaml:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <mynamespace:MyCustomAddDeleteTransition/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
```

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 8/8.1 - custom transitions like that are not supported, but you could write an attached behavior or subclass an `ItemsControl` to do that with regular `Storyboard` animations. For your specific scenario you could use the [`ContainerContentChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.containercontentchanging.aspx) event or override [`PrepareContainerForItemOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) and [`ClearContainerForItemOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.clearcontainerforitemoverride.aspx) in a custom `ListView` subclass to set up the animations.

In Windows 10 since about the time of the Anniversary Update (2016) you can also implement transitions using the [composition engine animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/composition-animation) that allows for some more powerful transitions.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine for PrepareContainerForItemOverride (a FlipIn Animation). But the animation fired in ClearContainerForItemOverride (FlipOut) will not play/finish, as the PrepareContainerForItemOverride for the same container is called just after, even when i put the base class call for clearing in the finished event of the Storyboard. So for now I will keep the standard transition. Maybe with an future update for WinRT we are able to create custom transitions ;)

Comment: You can get your container to use two content presenters and alternate between them, then animate only one that you are emptying/populating.

Comment: Animating the content presenter did the job, thank you very much :)